# How to compare numbers in an array

Tags: c#, arrays, comparison

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DiceGame
{
class Program
  {



    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random randomnumber = new Random();

        int[] Player = new int[5];
        Player[0] = randomnumber.Next(1, 6); 
        Player[1] = randomnumber.Next(1, 6); 
        Player[2] = randomnumber.Next(1, 6); 
        Player[3] = randomnumber.Next(1, 6); 
        Player[4] = randomnumber.Next(1, 6);
        Console.WriteLine("You rolled a " + Player[0] + " " + Player[1] + " " + Player[2] + " " + Player[3] + " " + Player[4]);
         Console.WriteLine(" You have a " + however many are equal);
    }
  }
}
```

edit: I need to compare multiple numbers in the array with each other. They are randoming 1-6, if 2 are equal to each other i need to display pair. If 3 are equal display three of a kind, if 4 four of a kind 5, five of a kind

edit2: the only thing i could find is this but it only compares the Player[0] to the rest of the array

```
for (int i = 0; i < Player.Length; i++)
        {
            int count = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < Player.Length; j++)
            {
                if (Player[i] == Player[j])
                    count = count + 1;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\t\n " + Player[i] + " occurs " + count);




            Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: You have just one array here. What do you want to compare it with?

Comment: What do you mean by "if 2 are equal"? (Using full English rather than text-speak is generally helpful on Stack Overflow, by the way.)

Comment: What have you tried?  Also, try using complete words, it makes it easier to read the question and you might look like you have some respect for the people helping.

Comment: with other numbers in the array

Comment: @RyanVanDusen Please show us what you have tried. Maybe this will shed more light on the actual problem.

Comment: @Kapol added what ive tried

Comment: You could also sort them since you may need to print them out.  Then counting occurrences might seem easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write this conventionally with `foreach` loops:

```
int theSame = 0;
foreach (var x in Player)
{    
     int localTheSame = 0;
     foreach (var y in Player)
     {
         if (x == y)
         {
             localTheSame++;
         }
     }

     if (localTheSame > theSame)
     {
         theSame = localTheSame;
     }
}
```

I wrote this answer before your edit2, so I thought you want to display the maximum occurrences of any number.

**EDIT**

The same solution using LINQ:

```
int theSame = Player.Max(x => Player.Count(y => x == y));
```

Comment: This works my edit two is saying that the the only thing ive tried only compares it to the first in the array i was looking for the maximum occurrences, Thanks a lot

Comment: @RyanVanDusen I added a solution using LINQ. If you're familiar with it, it's 1 line instead of around 15.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ to get count of each digit.

```
 Random randomnumber = new Random();

        int[] Player = new int[5];
        Player[0] = randomnumber.Next(1, 6); 
        Player[1] = randomnumber.Next(1, 6); 
        Player[2] = randomnumber.Next(1, 6); 
        Player[3] = randomnumber.Next(1, 6); 
        Player[4] = randomnumber.Next(1, 6);
        Console.WriteLine("You rolled a " + Player[0] + " " + Player[1] + " " + Player[2] + " " + Player[3] + " " + Player[4]);
        var selected = from x in Player.AsEnumerable()
                       group x by x into g
                       select new { Digit = g.Key, DigitCount = g.Count()};
     foreach(var sel in selected)
     {
       Console.WriteLine("You have rolled " + sel.Digit + " no of times " + sel.DigitCount);
     }
```

Comment: You should update answer by initializing each value of player inside a loop.

Comment: @KevinAvignon I just took what OP has posted and added the logic for what he wanted.Yes you are right initialization can be done inside loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as simple as that:

```
foreach (var p in Player.GroupBy(x => x).Select(x => new { Player = x.Key, Count = x.Count()}))
            Console.WriteLine("Player {0} occurs {1} time{2}", p.Player, p.Count, p.Count == 1 ? "s" : "");
```